# Select from two inherited tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, select, single-table-inheritance

Say there is a PostgreSQL parent table `files` that is empty; it's 'abstract'.   And then there are tables that inherit from `files` that contain data: `red-files`, `green-files`, `blue-files`.

I can select from all three by selecting from `files*`, but how can I select from both `red-files` and `green-files` only?

That is, if the query would retrieve 3 rows from `red-files` and 2 rows from `green-files`, then the combined query I'm looking for would show 5 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL unless there is a field to join its.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE files (
>     name            text,
>     size            int
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE redfiles (
>     id           char(2)
> ) INHERITS (files);
>
>
> CREATE TABLE bluefiles (
>     id           char(2)
> ) INHERITS (files);
> ```

> ```
> insert into redfiles (name, id, size) values ('file1','aa', 1024);
> insert into redfiles (name, id, size) values ('file2','bb', 2048);
> insert into bluefiles (name, id, size) values ('file3','xx', 1024);
> insert into bluefiles (name, id, size) values ('file4','yy', 1526);
> ```

> ```
> select * from files;
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | size
> :---- | ---:
> file1 | 1024
> file2 | 2048
> file3 | 1024
> file4 | 1526
> ```

> ```
> with MyFiles as
> (
>     select * from redfiles
>     union all
>     select * from bluefiles
> ) 
> select *
> from   MyFiles
> where  size = 1024;
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | size | id
> :---- | ---: | :-
> file1 | 1024 | aa
> file3 | 1024 | xx
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=32a229da58d24850aa00b234a1fe3653)*

Comment: See the edit in the original question -- hopefully now my question is clearer.

Comment: You construct each table's query separately and then apply a union.  So, there's no way to apply a single query to the tables together?  Say `files` has a column name `size`.  If I want a `where size > 500` to apply to all tables, it'd still need to be written for each table's individual query?

Comment: Is there any field that allows to join both tables?

Comment: This is what I was looking for: `with t as (
 select * from redfiles
 union all 
 select * from bluefiles
 )
select * from t where size > 500`.    Please add to your answer.

Comment: is `size` one attribute of your table schema?

Comment: `size` is a column in the `files` parent table, which I mentioned in the previous comment to better describe what I hoped to find; namely, a way to aggregate the tables and then have a single query qualifier.  Using a `with` along with your suggested `union all` is what I wanted.